# How do I recover files from the Offline Files Folder after unjoining a PC from a domain?

Tags: windows-xp, offline-files

While on the domain, the PC had Folder Redirection and Offline Files enabled. After it was unjoined, My Documents is empty, but all of the files that were previously synced to My Documents are stuck in the Offline Files Folder. I've attempted to copy them out, but I get an error (Error copying file. Cannot read source file from disk.). I'm guessing this is some kind of permissions issue, but I have no idea where the OFF is actually located on disk.

How do I recover all of these files? Bonus points if you can find a way to preserve the former folder structure too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`csccmd /extract` will do as you need. It's been a while so I can't remember exactly how to do it.

> /EXTRACT[:\Server\Share[\Path]] /TARGET:Path [/RECURSE] [/ONLYMODIFIED] [/STOPONERROR]
>                 Extract a file, a directory, or a directory tree from the local cache. 
>                 This requires Local Administrator permissions
>                 /TARGET will specify a destination.(which need not already exist)
>                 /ONLYMODIFIED, extract only files that have been modified offline.
>                 /STOPONERROR, stop the extract if an error occurs.

Reference from [SS64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/csccmd.html)